# Magento: Moved Multistore - new store always redirect to old domain, although new base_url

Tags: magento

I have moved a Multistore to another webserver with the following structrue:

```
mystore.com --> Magento Multistore installation
flowers.website.com --> symlinks to mystore.com folder
cars.website.com --> symlinks to mystore.com folder
```

The new setup is completely the same (only different domains and folder names).

But if I go to the new url `mynewstore.com` I will always be redirect to the old domain.
Things I have already done/tried:

- Changed the base_urls in core_config_data
- Cleared var + 777 permission
- Cleared session table
- Reindex
- Checked htaccess for redirects
- Checked index.php
- Checked templates of the different stores for redirects

The important part of my index.php:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
$mageRunCode = 'mystore';
$mageRunType = 'website';
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

If I'm going to change the `$mageRunCode` to another store ID (like "flowers"), the old (!!) flower store (redirect to old flower url) will be loaded.

I guess it is hard to solve the problem without looking at the code, but I've no other idea as to try it here. I really appreciate any hint.

Comment: Hi Hannes.

What web server are you running? There are better ways of doing this than  by editing index.php. 

Do you have MySQL server access?

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem and it took me almost a whole day to figure out what was going wrong. I had a multistore but all the stores gave a 404 page on every URL I tried. In the end the solution was to change `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` from `website` to `store`.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php file as you have it is overriding the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` variables because of these lines:

```
$mageRunCode = 'mystore';
$mageRunType = 'website';
```

Since they are called after their initial definitions, they;re being reset to `mystore` and `website`.

Try removing these lines, and seeing if the variables are properly passed into the `Mage::run()` function.

---

**Important Notice about CHMODing to 777**.

This is a potentially dangerous thing to do as it can allow public access to your filesystem.  You never want to set a **777** permission set on a production site for this reason.

**Set your folders to 755 and files to 644**.  To do this, open a shell connection and `cd` to your Magento root directory.  Run the following command:

```
chmod -R 755 *; find -type f -print0|xargs -0 chmod 644
```

If run correctly, all of the files in your Magento installation will be set to the correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your post makes sense, I changed the index.php. But unfortunately it is still redirecting to the old domain. Thank you also for the note to the permissions, I am going to change it.

Comment: You mentioned "old domain", so I'm assuming the domain name has changed to?  Are you absolutely sure you've updated and setup the domain names on the STORE level configuration in the Magento config?

Comment: Yes, I did a select * from core_config_data where path like "%base_url"; And I updated all these urls. And the new urls are correct. I know, it is really weird! But thank you for comment, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

in the index.php header add this:

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE'];
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE'];
```

Comment: Please explain to the author and future googlers what your answer actually does to solve the problem.  Bare code is not terribly informative